# illegal start of expression public boolean setTuitionFees;(double fees);{

Tags: java

I'm trying to create a method so I can set the "tuitionFees" and  "scholarships" as a double for the profile of the user of the program. I'm unsure if I'm even setting this up right.

```
    import java.util.Scanner;
    /**
    StudentInvoice.java
    Defines StudentInvoice objects
    @author: Evan Fravert
    */
    public class StudentInvoice {
    // declare instance variables here
    // constructor
    // methods
    // toString method (for String output)
       private String studentName;
       private String studentNumber;
       private double tuitionFees;
       private double scholarships;

    public String toString() {
     String output = "Name: " + studentName + "\n";
     output += "Student ID Number: " + studentNumber + "\n";
     output += "Tuition & Fees: " + tuitionFees + "\n";
     output += "Scholarship: " + scholarships + "\n";
     return output;
     }

    public StudentInvoice(String name, String number, double fees, double scholarship){
     studentName = name;
     studentNumber = number;
     tuitionFees = fees;
     scholarships = scholarship;
     }
    public boolean setStudentName(String name){
     if(name.length() == 0)
     {
     return false;
     }
     else
     {
     studentName = name;
     return true;
     }
     }
    public boolean setStudentNumber(String number){
     if(number.length() == 0)
     {
     return false;
     }
     else
     {
     studentNumber = number;
     return true;
     }  
    public boolean setTuitionFees(double fees){
     if(fees < 0.0) {
 return false;
 }
 else {
 tuitionFees = fees;
 return true;
 }
 }
 public boolean setScholarships (double scholarship){
 if(scholarship < 0.0) {
 return false;
 }
 else {
 Scholarships = scholarship;
 return true;
 }
    }
    }
    }
```

My class with the interactions:

```
    public class StudentInvoiceApp {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
    StudentInvoice Evan = new StudentInvoice("Evan Fravert");
    Evan.setName("Evan Fravert");
    Evan.setNumber(01234);
    Evan.setTuitionFees(0.00);
    Evan.setScholarship(0.00);
    System.out.print(Evan);
    }
    }
```

Comment: You're missing a `}` on the line before the error. If you indent your code better that would be very obvious. Your IDE, text editor or even something like astyle will do that automatically for you.

Answer (score 1):

Upon trying to edit your post, I discovered you had a missing brace after `setStudentNumber`. The corrected code with proper formatting is below. In any programming language, formatting your code is important to understanding its meaning. People write entire books on how to format code, and for good reason. With good formatting, you likely would have noticed the missing brace.

Searching for "How to format Java code" yields several useful conventions, including documents from Oracle about how they format their Java code. When in doubt, most IDE's provide shortcuts to format code as well. In Eclipse, it's `Ctrl+Shift+F`, and in NetBeans, it's `Alt+Shift+F`.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 * StudentInvoice.java Defines StudentInvoice objects
 * 
 * @author: Evan Fravert
 */
public class StudentInvoice {
    // declare instance variables here
    // constructor
    // methods
    // toString method (for String output)
    private String studentName;
    private String studentNumber;
    private double tuitionFees;
    private double scholarships;

    public String toString() {
        String output = "Name: " + studentName + "\n";
        output += "Student ID Number: " + studentNumber + "\n";
        output += "Tuition & Fees: " + tuitionFees + "\n";
        output += "Scholarship: " + scholarships + "\n";
        return output;
    }

    public StudentInvoice(String name, String number, double fees,
            double scholarship) {
        studentName = name;
        studentNumber = number;
        tuitionFees = fees;
        scholarships = scholarship;
    }

    public boolean setStudentName(String name) {
        if (name.length() == 0) {
            return false;
        } else {
            studentName = name;
            return true;
        }
    }

    public boolean setStudentNumber(String number) {
        if (number.length() == 0) {
            return false;
        } else {
            studentNumber = number;
            return true;
        }
    }

    public boolean setTuitionFees(double fees) {
        if (fees < 0.0) {
            return false;
        } else {
            tuitionFees = fees;
            return true;
        }
    }

    public boolean setScholarships(double scholarship) {
        if (scholarship < 0.0) {
            return false;
        } else {
            scholarships = scholarship;
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

change your setStudentNumber method to this

```
 public boolean setStudentNumber(String number){
 if(number.length() == 0)
 {
 return false;
 }
 else
 {
 studentNumber = number;
 return true;
 }
 }
```

you were missing an closing brace for else